# JPanel with drawing issues

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, awt

What I want is a dynamic line between my coordinate source and a red dot.
The red dot should leave a trace of dots behind, as I repaint, while the line should not leave a trace behind.

Right now neither line nor dot leave a trace since I `super.paintComponent(gfx)`.
Any idea how can I achieve the dynamic line and the trace-leaving dot?
The classes below are compileable, so you can reconstruct my issue.

My Main and JPanel classes are:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String Args[])
    {
        //Initialize Points
        ArrayList<Point> carthCoords = new ArrayList<Point>();
        Point p1 = new Point(300,300);
        Point p2 = new Point(-300,-200);
        carthCoords.add(p1);
        carthCoords.add(p2);

        //Create JPanel
        CoordSystem coordPanel = new CoordSystem(800, 800, carthCoords);

        //Display Points on JFrame
        JFrame jFrame = new JFrame("Points and Vectors");
        jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jFrame.setSize(800, 800);
        javax.swing.Timer t = new javax.swing.Timer(10, coordPanel);
        jFrame.add(coordPanel);
        t.start();
        jFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

And the JPanel class:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class CoordSystem extends JPanel implements ActionListener{
    public int W;
    public int H;
    ArrayList<Point> points;

    public CoordSystem(int width, int height, ArrayList<Point> pointz) 
    {
        this.W = width;
        this.H = height;
        this.points = pointz;
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics gfx)
    {
        super.paintComponent(gfx);
        setBackground(Color.white);
        //Draw Coordinate System
        gfx.setColor(Color.blue);
        gfx.drawLine(W/2, 0, W/2, H);
        gfx.drawLine(0, H/2, W, H/2);

        //Draw Points
        if (points != null)
        {
            int x,y;
            for (Point p : points)
            {
                x = (int)p.getX();
                y = (int)p.getY();
                gfx.setColor(Color.red);
                gfx.fillOval((W/2) + x, (H/2) - y, 10, 10);
                gfx.setColor(Color.black);
                gfx.drawLine(W/2 + x,H/2 - y, W/2, H/2);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        for (Point point : points)
        {
            point.translate(0,-1);
        }
        repaint();
    }
}
```

Comment: I can think of a number of ways you might solve it, but I'm not entirely sure I understand your problem or what you are trying to achieve. Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: I added how my Panel gets put in the JFrame.
So my problem still is that I want a moving point on the JPanel and it should leave a trace of everywhere it has been. The problem is that all other objects that I'm painting on this JPanel leave a trace too (which I dont want).